# Angular-ui-grid - text-decoration doesn't apply to row template children

Tags: css, angularjs, row, angular-ui-grid, text-decorations

I am able to set the row background colour by applying the following CSS to row template in AngularJS UI grid:

```
    .deleted {
        background-color: #e3e3e3 !important;
    }
```

It works well. However, when I add

```
text-decoration: line-through !important;
```

It doesn't apply to text within the row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could/would you share a plunker showing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have unnecessarily added this style:

```
.ui-grid-row .ui-grid-cell {
               background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

And to get the desired effect I simply had to change the row template in the following way:

```
$scope.gridOptions= {
        rowTemplate: '<div>'+
        '<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" ' +
        'class="ui-grid-cell" ' +
        ' ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader, deleted: row.entity.deleted}" ui-grid-cell></div></div>'}
```

Where **deleted: row.entity.deleted** is the condition setting my class.